# BME280 on Raspberry Pi using Python 3 - Odd first reading

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have 2 x Pimoroni BME280 and they both produce the same initial reading of 21.95*C 698.09hPa 76.34% humidity.

Using this simple code

```
import time
from smbus2 import SMBus
from bme280 import BME280
bus = SMBus(1)
bme280 = BME280(i2c_dev=bus)
while True:
    temperature = bme280.get_temperature()
    pressure = bme280.get_pressure()
    humidity = bme280.get_humidity()
    print('{:05.2f}*C {:05.2f}hPa {:05.2f}%'.format(temperature, pressure, humidity))
    time.sleep(1)
```

and I always get as the first line of output as...

> 21.95*C  698.09hPa  76.34%

followed by the correct data for example...

> 18.70*C 993.54hPa 55.88%

> 18.70*C 993.53hPa 56.12%

> 18.71*C 993.54hPa 56.06%

> 18.71*C 993.54hPa 55.95%

Does anybody know why this is?

Currently I have the same thing on both of my BME280 so presume it's some sort of initialization thing on the first reading which must be discarded. If I run my program the only solution I can see it to ask twice what thr readings are and discard the first reading..

Thanks for reading and helping...

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that this is caused due to an initial transient value being outputted by the sensor as a result of initialising your sensor.

It would be interesting to see how an Arduino would handle the initialisation process
vis-à-vis said transient value with your sensor.

As you said, if your continuous readings are 'correct', I would try to perhaps delay the output process or omit the first reading in some way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this, and am having success by initializing the bme280 library in 'forced' mode:

```
from bme280 import BME280

try:
    from smbus2 import SMBus
except ImportError:
    from smbus import SMBus

# Must be set up in 'forced' mode to discard the initial junk readings
bme280 = BME280(i2c_dev=SMBus(1))
bme280.setup(mode='forced')

temperature = bme280.get_temperature()
```